# Swagger equivalent path error even though paths are different

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

```
✖ Swagger Error
Equivalent path already exists: /profile/address/{id}

✖ Swagger Error
Equivalent path already exists: /profile/qualifications/{id}
```

In Swagger editor I get this error. If you see.. paths are different.. even though it throws this error. Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: From what I've experienced the error reporting isn't that accurate in Swagger Editor. You might have a syntax error somewhere up the chain